# @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) not working/ jackson serializing null values

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I have placed the annotation over the class/pojo and also configured the mapper, but it still **serialize** **null** values

I am using Hibernate 4.3.7Final and Jackson 2.4.4. The collections are **lazy loaded**

Pojo : Removed getter and setters

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@Entity
@Table
public class School {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Student> students;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Employee> staff;

}
```

JSONMapper:

```
@Component
public class JSONMapper extends ObjectMapper {
/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3131980955975958812L;

//ref http://blog.pastelstudios.com/2012/03/12/spring-3-1-hibernate-4-jackson-module-hibernate/ 

    public JSONMapper() {

        Hibernate4Module hm = new Hibernate4Module();
        registerModule(hm);
        configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT , false);
        configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
        setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);  
    }
}
```

Output :

```
{"id":1,"students":null,"staff":null}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using [JsonInclude.NON_EMPTY](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_EMPTY) instead.

Comment: I want to include empty because it shows a list exist and its empty. But null  means it's not loaded. Basically struggling with hibernate Lazy object. I don't wanna show proxies.

Comment: You should always use empty Lists instead of null values. That's because Hibernate will always use proxies, even when there's no associated child, meaning that the only time you have a null value is when you create the Parent object for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to file a bug against project; it could be that handling for lazy-loaded collections (which do require special handling and overrides to default one) is not doing proper inclusion checks.